# Choice of Primitive Element in ''Primitive Element Theorem''

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and $K$ a finite extension of $F$. Then it is well known ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)) that $K$ can be obtained by attaching an element $\alpha \in K$ to $F$, i.e. $K=F(\alpha)$.

**Question:** Is it *always* possible to choose $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^m\in K$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: For my curiosity, do you know how to find such $\alpha$ for $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$?

Comment: You’re asking whether every extension is radical.

Comment: @Lubin: Probably your statement is exactly what I mentioned in question.

Comment: Oh, well, then look closely at the suggestion of @GitGud; or else just take a normal extension of $\Bbb Q$ of degree three. If it were generated by a cube root, then the cube roots of unity would be there too, no good because the cube roots of unity are quadratic over $\Bbb Q$.